# Make Hibernate nullify and not drop a join table row when item from collection is removed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We have two DAO entities, `Customer` and `Record`.

Record has two lists of customers, `typeA` and `typeB`.

We have a table per class schema, so there is a join table `RECORD_X_CUSTOMER`.  This table has columns `RECORD_ID`, `TYPEA_ID`, and `TYPEB_ID`.

The problem is that we have some entries in this join table that contain both a `typeA id` and a `typeB id` in the same table row.  In the application, if we remove a typeA and there is also a typeB on the record, they will both be removed and vice versa.  Is there a way to have Hibernate nullify the column as apposed to deleting the entire table row?

Here are the class annotations:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
    name="TYPEA_X_CUSTOMER"
    , joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="RECORD_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
        }
    , inverseJoinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="TYPEA_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
        }
    )       
@BatchSize(size=1000)
protected List<Customer> typeA;

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
    name="TYPEB_X_CUSTOMER"
    , joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="RECORD_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
        }
    , inverseJoinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="TYPEB_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
        }
    )
@BatchSize(size=1000)
protected List<Customer> typeB;
```

Comment: The code doesn't match the description you gave: it uses two different join tables. Where is the truth?

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry, those are really just views.

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible. Either match exactly to the tables by mapping the join table as an entity and handle the mess by yourself, or normalize your schema to make it look like mapped in your code: two join tables - one for each association.

Comment: @JBNizet Add this as the answer and I will accept.  The reason that we have data like this is because we migrated data from another database schema.  I was hoping that we might could handle it with JPA rather than write scrips to fix it.  Thanks!